# Arduino Due and Vin, 3.3V and 5V power inputs

Tags: power, arduino-due, voltage-level

I just want to confirm something before I wire up my first ever Arduino project and fry all the stuff I just spent money on.

It is my *understanding* that the `Vin` power input will tolerate a 9V battery and use voltage regulators to pare it down to either 3.3V or 5V (as different parts of the board require). So it is then my *assumption* that if I have a 9V battery running to `Vin`, that I could then connect a power wire to the `3.3V` connector, and reliably get a 3.3V signal (and ditto for 5V), **yes?**

Or, is it that they are *input* jacks *expecting* either 3.3V or 5V signals? I guess I'm confused over this:

- Will `Vin` then power the 3.3V and 5V inputs, giving me access to voltage at that level; or
- Do I have to choose between 3.3V, 5V or `Vin`, and only use one of those to power my board (with the appropriate voltage level)

Comment: Have you checked the schematic yet?

Comment: If you can provide a schematic I'll check it out and maybe it answers my question, but I'm so new to electronics, I may not even be able to make sense of it.

Comment: All Arduino product pages link to a schematic for the board.

Comment: Then I would assume [this](http://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-Due-schematic.pdf) is what you mean, in which case, I cannot at this exact moment make sense of it. And although I *think* I can guess your next argument, which is probably "*Well then you need to learn how to read schematics, otherwise get out of electronics*", I would counter-argue that Arduino is from the ground-up aimed at complete electronics newbies like myself. And that this is a basic usage question that should be answer-able without a moderate understanding of EE/ECE.

Comment: And yes, in time, I will learn this stuff, but I shouldn't have to be able to read that diagram and fully comprehend it to understand how to connect my board to a battery.

Comment: The power subsections are on the bottom right of the page. Unmarked, of course, because that's how Arduino rolls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DC Jack` is connected, through a diode, to `Vin`.

`Vin` is stepped down to `5V` on-board.

`5V` is stepped down to `3V3` on board.

Thus you can do any one of the following numbered items.

1. Connect a 7-12V supply to the `DC Jack`; thus:

   - use `Vin` as a supply @ DC - 0.7V for off-board peripherals, and
   - use `5V` as a supply for off-board peripherals, and
   - use `3V3` as a supply for off-board peripherals.
2. Connect a 6-12V supply to `Vin`; thus:

   - use `5V` as a supply for off-board peripherals, and
   - use `3V3` as a supply for off-board peripherals.
3. Connect 5V supply to the `5V`; thus:

   - use `3V3` as a supply for off-board peripherals.

The above is only guaranteed for boards that **follow the reference schematic**, as plenty of clone/compatible boards do. If you buy a cheap Chinarduino and something doesn't work, or the thing breaks, after following anything above then that's your tough luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your assumption is correct you can power 3.3v and 5v items from those pins as long as you don't take more current than the onboard regulator(s) can supply